# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface & configparser

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm newbie here and I wouldn't want to ask such a easy question as my first post but I don't know anything about Python even I'm a PHP/C programmer.

I have a python script in Figway tools which is called RegisterDevice.py to register my own sensor hardware to [FIWARE Lab](http://www.fi-ware.org). But some code lines of that script doesn't work as I expected because of Python3.4. This may not be my problem but I don't have too much time to wait an official solution that's why I thought that I could resolve it as a person who is familiar to the programming.

I've searched on the web for solution but I couldn't find any exact solution for it yet. As far as I read bytes and unicode strings are two different types in Python3.x but I couldn't realize where I have to encode or maybe decode string to other type on the code. Maybe I have to do something else...

Here is the part of script which gave me error like above.

```
# Load the configuration file
with open(CONFIG_FILE,'r+') as f:
    sample_config = f.read()
#config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config = configparser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
config.readfp(io.BytesIO(sample_config))
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RegisterDevice.py", line 47, in <module>
    config.readfp(io.BytesIO(sample_config))
TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface
```

Comment: Try using `open(CONFIG_FILE,'rb+')`, i.e, open the file as **binary**, so the `read` will return **bytes** as desired rather than a Unicode **string**.

Comment: Yeap I've tried it before but didn't work, also error was changed. `TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str` This error comes from python3.4/configparser.py

Comment: Looks like that script is quite incompatible with Python 3.4, as it's using bytes and strings as interchangeable (as they were in Python 2).  Unless you can get an updated version of the script, your choices are to install and use Python 2.7 or perhaps try hacking the script into 3.* compatibility with the `2to3` tool (the latter's not trivial if you don't know anything about Python; the former is trivially easy for anybody, I think).

Comment: Can you change the file? It should have just been `config.read(CONFIG_FILE)` and shouldn't have opened the file at all.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly `readfp()` is deprecated in Python3 and you should use `read_file()`.

The best way is probably using the `read()` function directly when you want to work with a file. You should set encoding as the second parameter if you expect non-ASCII characters inside the file.

The alternative is to `read_string()` and give it a string directly.

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing work very similar to this, and I believe this script runs, but you will have to verify if it gives you the desired results:

```
import configparser

with open('.coveragerc','r+') as f:
#config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    config = configparser.RawConfigParser(allow_no_value=True)
    config.readfp(f)
```